# Tensorflow installation error: GPU version on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu-16.04

I have tried to install gpu version of tensorflow from following 2 method but getting same error at last step:

https://alliseesolutions.wordpress.com/2016/09/08/install-gpu-tensorflow-from-sources-w-ubuntu-16-04-and-cuda-8-0-rc/

https://pythonprogramming.net/how-to-cuda-gpu-tensorflow-deep-learning-tutorial/

Error is

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 328, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 748, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 360, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 448, in _prepare_file
    req_to_install, finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 387, in _check_skip_installed
    req_to_install.check_if_exists()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1011, in check_if_exists
    self.req.project_name
AttributeError: 'Requirement' object has no attribute 'project_name'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use our official installation procedures:
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/get_started/os_setup.html

For questions on build/install, we monitor issues on http://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it. It is because of old pip version. I am unable to update pip in the targeted folder because I was using anaconda2. Once I switched back to default python2.7 and upgraded the pip, it worked.